# Searching best practice for passing data between vaadin UIs

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am new to vaadin and I am trying to build a web application with multiple pages using data from SQL Server. Thanks to my research in several StackOverflow topics I could get the first page to work, showing some basic data of my Person entity in a grid.

Now when I select one record in the grid and click on a button, I want to open a second page and use the ID of the selected Person (`person.getId()`) to load additional data from the backend to a FormLayout (in this case contact information).

At the moment, I have made my application open the second page, but without data. My second page has `@Route("/contact")` annotation and I am using `ui.navigate("/contact")` in the first page, to navigate to the second page.

Yesterday I spent some hours reading about Blackboard EventBus to pass data between pages. I got to work a simple example where the first page fires a person event and the second page listens to those events and displays the person with `System.out.println()`. But how do I use this event / person data to refresh my second vaadin page? As in the Blackboard code sample, my Blackboard Bus is static.

As mentioned earlier, I want to select a person and then navigate to another page to load additional information for this person. If the user navigates back to the first page and selects another person, again clicks the button to navigate to the second page, the second page should refresh and display the data for the newly selected person.

At the moment, my second pages loads, but crashes with `NullPointerException`, because the selectedPerson variable is empty and I do not understand how to use the Blackboard Listener to refresh the UI with the retrieved person data from the event.

I do not really know how to proceed and at the moment.

Comment: I can highly recommend reading through the [Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/Overview.html) page before implementing your application further. Im sure you will learn about other best practices too while reading through it. What you are looking for is the [HasUrlParameter interface](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/routing/tutorial-router-url-parameters.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you pass the id of the person as a parameter instead. Something like this (untested code)

```
FirstView

button.addClickListener(event -> {
    ui.navigate(ContactPage.class, selectedPerson.getId());
}
```

And then the other page

```
@Route("contact")
public class ContactPage extends ... implements HasUrlParameter<Long> {
...
    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, Long parameter) {
        if (parameter != null) {
            // Load additional info
        } else {
            Notfication.show("Blablabla");
            // Or
            event.rerouteToError(someError);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. And I also followed the advice of Kaspar Scherrer above and spent the evening reading the Documentation again and in detail. I will continue reading the whole doc for the next days to get a better theoretical understanding before the next implementation steps.

Comment: Sounds like a great plan! The ability to comment on the documentation was recently added (through `Start a discussion` at the bottom of each page), so if something you read is unclear, don't hesitate to comment on it :)